# How to allow a wpf control to fill its grid cell when resized using splitter but also have a default width

Tags: wpf, binding, grid, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I have a situation where I have 2 columns inside tabs. The 2nd column can be hidden. Problem is better explained with pictures :

**The initial Tab without the 2nd column showing should look like this, so it is correct :**

[image: sss]

**And the channel tab should also look like so which is also correct :**

[image]

**But when I resize the 2nd column using a grid splitter the listbox stays of fixed width instead of stretching. I want it to stretch :**

[image]

**Now after the resize of the 2nd tab listbox the first tab has a blank area which is unwanted :**

[image]

**Code :**

```
<TabControl x:Name="tcTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" DisplayMemberPath="Raw" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" />
                            <GridSplitter ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3" />
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" DisplayMemberPath="Nick" Visibility="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource UserListVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBBBBBB" Width="130" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBBBBBB" Height="22" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would put GridSplitter in its own column. Second, make sure your final column has proportional sizing too. Third, don't set a fixed width on your right-most `ListBox`. If you want it to have a minimum width, set `MinWidth`. So your XAML would look something like:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" DisplayMemberPath="Raw" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" />
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" DisplayMemberPath="Nick" Visibility="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource UserListVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBBBBBB" MinWidth="130" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBBBBBB" Height="22" />
```

Comment: That makes the user list half the width of the whole form by default, and also now it displays 50% blank space when it shouldnt in the server window too.

Comment: @MuhammadA, maybe this answer didn't give your exact desired result, but this is definitely the way to go... I would agree with what Kent has said. Maybe you should take this code and experiment with it until you have what you want, rather than just saying 'it doesn't fit your purpose?